# How can I change soap address in a JBoss 7 java webservice

Tags: java, jax-ws, jboss7.x

How can I change the soap address in a web service. I'm working on JBoss 7.1.1.

I have this web service class:

```
@WebService
public class Card {

   @WebMethod
   public CardResponseDTO insertCard(
           @WebParam(name = "cardRequestCardDTO") CardDTO cardDTO,
           @WebParam(name = "userName") String userName) {

       Date today;
       CardResponseDTO cardResponseDTO = new CardResponseDTO();

       try {
            today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            // My logic in here...
            return cardResponseDTO;
       } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            cardResponseDTO.setErrorCode(-2);
            cardResponseDTO.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
            return cardResponseDTO;
       }
   }
}
```

And when I'm working at my localhost works fine with this WSDL:

```
<wsdl:service name="CardService">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:CardServiceSoapBinding" name="CardPort">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/inventory-ws/Card"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

But when I deploy to my server, that has a name server1.somedomain.com, doesn't work because I got just http:// server1:8080/ ...

```
<wsdl:service name="CardService">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:CardServiceSoapBinding" name="CardPort">
     <soap:address location="http://server1:8080/inventory-ws/Card"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

What I need is how to make it work in my server with the complete url: server1.domedomain.com.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure jboss to listen to the interface you want.
To do so you have to edit the standalone.xml file and add some new interface tags.
I think this post might be useful.
https://community.jboss.org/message/614897

Comment: Thanks @ppapapetrou, I just make the change on standalone.xml 
   <wsdl-host>www.myhost.com</wsdl-host>

Answer (score 14):

If you need to deploy SOAP web services for public access e.g. via Apache you can remove in the *standalone.xml* this line: `<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>` at all.
Then the host name will be taken over from the WSDL URL. 
In this case you do not need to change the configuration for every deployment stage. For example *dev.myhost.com, qa.myhost.com or ww.myhost.com.*

This avoids also the problem with wrong SSL port 8443 for public services.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify,

In the standalone.xml, just under the tag:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
```

You must modify these entries

```
<modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
<wsdl-host>www.myhost.com</wsdl-host>
```

**To change port:**

```
<wsdl-port>80</wsdl-port> <!-- case you need change port, instead 8080 -->
<wsdl-secure-port>443</wsdl-secure-port> <!-- case you need change port, instead 8443 -->
```

**To change URI Schema:**

```
<wsdl-uri-scheme>https</wsdl-uri-scheme> <!-- or http for non secure -->
```

Comment: How do we handle the port? In my case I do not want the port to appear in the soap address, but it does. There is no way to override this my supplying wsdl-port as blank as it throws parsing error.

Comment: Try this.              ** <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host> **
This will take whatever hostname you have binded and if you use port 80 it will not show up.