# How to override wsdl soap-address within the ear under wildfly?

Tags: web-services, soap, jboss, wsdl, wildfly

We have an ear application, that contains some WS endpoints. I have to deploy to the target server but I have to override the WSDL soap-address tag. The solution we use our local testbed is following this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23491951 That works perfectly. (server is wildfly 8.2)

However we cannot use this solution anymore on production server ("just because").

I found, that there is a `jboss-webservices.xml`, that should override the wsdl's `<soap-address>` tag without changing the `standalone.xml` / `domain.xml`'s `webservices` subsystem settings.

But it is not working for me. My `jboss-webservices.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webservices version="1.2"
     xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss_webservices_1_0.xsd">
    <property>
        <name>wsdl.soapAddress.rewrite.modify-wsdl-address</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>wsdl.soapAddress.rewrite.wsdl-host</name>
        <value>somedomain.com</value>
    </property>
</webservices>
```

These instructions are followed:

- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Published+WSDL+customization
- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Advanced+User+Guide

I place `jboss-webservices.xml` both two places referred by the documentation:

- `META-INF/jboss-webservices.xml` for EJB webservice deployments
- `WEB-INF/jboss-webservices.xml` for POJO webservice deployments and EJB webservice endpoints bundled in war archives

Non of them works.

The related log snippet:

```
11:50:43,502 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=ABCServicePortType
 address=http://localhost:8180/abc-web/ABCServicePortType
 implementor=example.service.v1.impl.ABCServicePortTypeImpl
 serviceName={http://example.com/ns/mod/ws/ABCService/v1}ABCService
 portName={http://example.com/ns/mod/ws/ABCService/v1}ABCServicePortTypeImplPort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
```

**My questions:** May I miss something? Is there any other way to override `soap-address`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The properties that you provided in `jboss-webservices.xml` works but with a higher version of WildFly than you are using in your server (since WildFly 9). See webservices section of release notes for WildFly 9:

http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/02/WildFly9-Final-Released/

It looks that before WildFly 9 release `standalone.xml` is the only one place to customize WSDL generation.